# Как подменить видео- и аудио потоки на андроиде?

Tags: android, камера

Стоит задача на чистом андроиде (не эмуляторе) написать программу, которая создает виртуальную камеру на андроиде и подменяет камеру девайса на видео- и аудиопотоки видео из галереи устройства. Есть подобная программа для линукса, использующая v4l и создающая виртуальный девайс (dev/video2) в который идет стрим с помощью ffmpeg. В чем будет ключевое отличие проги для линукса и андроида?

Comment: В чем будет ключевое отличие проги для линукса и андроида? - целевая ось :D

Comment: Android, на лункс уже вышло такое реализовать